# UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle: Why is the download not using the available bandwidth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I have an application (platform: Android) where I need to download asset bundles from a server. In order to do so I'm using `UnityWebRequest` objects:

```
public IEnumerator GetAssetBundleAsync(string url, Action<AssetBundle> OnSuccess)
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(url))
        {
            yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();                
            AssetBundle bundle = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(uwr);
            if (OnSuccess != null)
                OnSuccess(bundle);
        }
}
```

Now I have done some performance testing (see the graph: [image: Download Throughput]). 'In Unity' indicates the data throughput when my application (on Android) does the download. 'In Browser' indicates, however, the throughput when downloaded directed in the browser of my Windows laptop. Both devices are connected to the same WIFI. As you can see, the maximum throughput is way higher for the latter.

Does anyone have an idea why the throughput is limited when downloading from inside the Unity app and how to maximize it?

Comment: @mjwills i don't see image too, so i don't think so :)

Comment: I think you missed to post the image Benjamin

Comment: Thank you guys, it's there now!

Comment: Hard to say without more information. One possibility is that the browser is making several requests in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass the problem doing the following by downloading the data as raw bytes and loading them as asset bundle from memory:

```
public IEnumerator GetAssetBundleByRawBytes(string url, Action<AssetBundle> onSuccess)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        var bundle = AssetBundle.LoadFromMemory(uwr.downloadHandler.data);
        if (onSuccess != null)
            onSuccess(bundle);
    }
}
```

This way all the available bandwidth is being used.